# How do I enable mobile payment options (Apple Pay/Google Pay) when using Gravity Forms?

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments, gravity-forms-plugin, applepay

I'm trying to make a website for a local non-profit, and on the donate page let users be able to make a donation on their phone via mobile payment processor (i.e. Google Pay/Apple Pay/ etc.). I'm using Wordpress as the CMS, and the Gravity Forms plugin with the Stripe Add on as the form creator (https://docs.gravityforms.com/stripe-add-on/). I see on Stripe Developer docs that they (Stripe) should support Apple Pay/Google Pay (https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button).  However I can not figure out how to enable this when using Gravity forms.

How do I enable mobile payment options (Apple Pay/Google Pay) when using Gravity Forms? Preferably using the Stripe add-on.

Comment: Were you able to get this working with Stripe and Gravity Forms? We are also a not-for-profit doing a similar thing on our website!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that stumbles on this question, you can allow both Apple Pay and Google Pay using the latest version of the Gravity Forms Stripe Add-On. To accomplish this you'll need to use Stripe Checkout as the "Payment Collection Method". You can read more about this within the Gravity Forms documentation at https://docs.gravityforms.com/stripe-payment-collection-methods/#2-stripe-payment-form-stripe-checkout-.